# MongoDb: aggregation $lookup

Tags: mongodb, filter, lookup, aggregation

Given following collections.
I have to get the title field and combine to identifier

CREDENTIAL:

```
{
    _id: ..
    title: ..
}
```

USER_CREDENTIAL:

```
{
    _id: ..
    credential_id: .. (from credential collection)
    created_at: ..
    identifier: {
        first_name: ..
        middle_name: ..
        last_name: ..
    }
}
```

The response should be:

```
{
   user_credential_id: 
   member: {
        first_name:
        middle_name:
        last_name:
        title:
        created_at:
    }
}
```

Comment: I have undone what seems to be an accidental removal of most of the info of your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. `$lookup` - Join `user` and `user_credential_id` with a pipeline to match the condition (`$match`) and decorate the document (`$project`).
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `member` array to multiple documents.
3. `$project` - Decorate the output document.

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user_credential",
      let: {
        "user_credential_id": "$_id",
        "title": "$title"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$credential_id",
                "$$user_credential_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            first_name: "$identifier.first_name",
            middle_name: "$identifier.middle_name",
            last_name: "$identifier.last_name",
            title: "$$title",
            created_at: "$created_at",
            
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "member"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$member"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_credential_id: "$_id",
      member: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TgDtEVyRZVf)

Comment: the result is empty array

Comment: what is the $match?

Comment: Can you provide sample document to prove? [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator is for filtering documents that match the filter criteria.

Comment: I want to use the aggregate in method in nodejs sooo that's why, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query

```
db.user.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "credentials",
      localField: "credential_id",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "user_credential"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$user_credential"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      user_credential_id: "$credential_id",
      member: {
        first_name: "$identifier.first_name",
        middle_name: "$identifier.middle_name",
        last_name: "$identifier.last_name",
        title: "$user_credential.title",
        created_at: "$created_at",
        
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can check it out [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oJIzHWnOs-w)

Comment: the result is empty array

Comment: what is the $match?

Comment: According to your question, you didn't specify that you want your query to match some value, all you wanted is to integrate title field and combine it to identifier for each doc based on user_credential. This is first, second you're saying that you're getting an empty array as a result, that's weird, did you try the link I left in the post?. https://mongoplayground.net/p/oJIzHWnOs-w

Comment: I want to use the aggregate in method in nodejs sooo that's why, can you help me?

Comment: mongoose in schema